# json object missing root element when returned from api

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-core

I try to invoke a method in an `api` using `jquery`, but I get an error saying

> XML Parsing Error: no root element found

The API method:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetJob(int id)
{
    var result = await this.DB.GetJob(id);

    return Ok(result);
}
```

**JQuery:**

```
function InvokeAjax (controller, action, method, query = {}, body = {}, callback) {
    let url = "/Secure/" + controller + "/" + action;

    if (query.length > 0) {
        let tmp;
        let i = 1;

        query.each(function (index) {
            if (i === 1) {
                tmp = "?";
            }
            else {
                tmp += "&";
            }

            tmp = this.key + "=" + this.value;

            i++;
        });

        url += tmp;
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: method.toUpperCase(),
        url: url,
        data: JSON.stringify(body),
        dataType: "JSON",
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (result) {
            if (callback !== null && callback !== "undefined") {
                callback(result);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The error says `xml` parsing error, is this the problem? I have defined `JSON` as return type so I don't know.

This is what gets returned from the `api`:

> {"clientId":3,"finished":false,"dateLastInvoked":"2018-09-09T04:07:40.8996335","name":"Jobb
>   nr 3","description":"Enda en jobb","items":[{"jobId":3,"comment":"løst
>   gåten","items":[{"timeIntervalId":3,"dateEnd":null,"state":2,"differenceRaw":201.21893158,"difference":3.4,"id":4,"uId":"6ad40e18-7e18-489f-9503-da25eac533a1","active":true,"dateCreated":"2018-09-09T04:07:41.1398231","helper":{}},{"timeIntervalId":3,"dateEnd":null,"state":3,"differenceRaw":201.21897233333334,"difference":3.4,"id":5,"uId":"2e3bad04-e454-4241-8aa4-0f6a124e6837","active":true,"dateCreated":"2018-09-09T04:07:41.1398254","helper":{}}],"differenceRaw":402.43795291833334,"difference":6.7,"state":2,"id":3,"uId":"82de2d44-8de7-49c0-8674-08e8b579c4ae","active":true,"dateCreated":"2018-09-09T04:07:41.0085169","helper":{}}],"timeSpentRaw":402.43801081333334,"timeSpent":6.7,"state":2,"running":true,"id":3,"uId":"cbd16771-3a1b-409f-9e67-515d03eb5116","active":true,"dateCreated":"2018-09-09T04:07:40.8996351","helper":{}}

Answer (score 0):

JSON is definitely not xml. But I think `dataType` is case sensitive. Or better use `$.getJSON`: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Anyway you should check your ajax call as it looks you are not using the parameters correctly.

Comment: so the returned json is ok? the browser parses it correctly so I think the returned data should be ok

Comment: Yes, the returned yson looks ok - but your call forces it to look for xml. Dont overconfigere ajax calls. Use shorthands and be sure to use correct parameters. This is all you need for ajax get: `$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success
});`

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to set `content-type: application/json` header at API end.

> I am assuming the error is at client side.

You should use `JSON()` instead of `OK()`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. I set contentType in the ajax call. I can't find any property named content-type

Comment: it turned out there was an error with the url, so it works fine now. thanks!